# R merge matrices with function

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to merge two matrices with different length on their incommon row.names with a function:

My first matrix (T) looks similar to this:

```
  1   2  3  4 
1 -4  3  2  2
1 2   1  1  5
2 3  -2  4  6
2 -2  1  -1 -9
```

Now I want to join this function into my new matrix (M), however in this matrix there should be only the colsum of the matching rows which are >=0 plus 1:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 2 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2
```

I tried following formula, which I found here in the forum, however it does not work:

```
merge.default(as.data.frame(M), as.data.frame(T), by = "row.names",  function(x){colSums(T[,]>0)+1})
```

Do you have an idea, where my mistake is?

Thank you very much

EDIT: my desired output would be my Matrix T, which is at the moment empty:

T now:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 
2
```

T after merge which is now filled with the function:

```
colsums(T[,] >=0)+1

  1 2 3 4
1 2 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2
```

T[1,1]= 2 as there is 1 value in Matrix M which is >=0 and then I add 1 to it

T[2,1]= 3 : two values >=0 and plus 1

Comment: merging require by to be a column name, It is not clear what you want but not a merge

Comment: What should the result look like? And please use `dput` or just some table-making code to make your example reproducible.

Comment: Explain !!! what you want on the result matrix why is T[1,1]=2, T[1,2]=3, ...

Comment: Is it now clearer?